EPIC FHIR Backend Services NOT able to get the access token (Production Environment)
I am trying to integrate the EPIC FHIR Backend Services APIs to the project I am currently working on. I am having trouble obtaining the access token necessary to reach the API endpoints for production, but the sandbox environment is working fine.
Here are the steps we have taken so far:

I created the Public Private Key Pair by following the instructions in the Creating a Public-Private Key Pair for JWT Signature guide.

I created the JWT by following Creating a Public-Private Key Pair for JWT Signature


It gives me error  {error: 'invalid_client', error_description: null} When I was trying to get the access token with using the production-client-id

Pretty hard to know what the issue is without code or more details. Some common pitfalls/things to check would be: make sure the exp claim is no more than five minutes in the future, make sure you are using the correct URL in the aud claim, make sure you've waited up to 12 hours to allow the public key to sync to the customer's production environment, resubmit the public key to trigger a re-sync, verify you are signing your JWT correctly using the tester at https://jwt.io.

To make a backend connection to a production server, you need to work with the IT administrators for the health system you are connecting to.  They will need to activate your client ID, and configure the appropriate access for your application before you can successfully connect.  This normally would involve signing contracts (usually including a business associates agreement), going security review, testing, etc.
